# Pass document object to function

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript code written following the module pattern:

```
var controller = function () {

    return {
        init: function() {
            // settings and initialization    
        }

        makeUIactions: function() { 
             //set UI actions, for example callback function of a button:
            document.getElementById("ShuffleButton").addEventListener("click", Shuffle);
            function Shuffle(){};
        }
    }
}
```

How do I pass by document object to makeUIactions?

P/S: I got the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

Is it because I can't access document from makeUIactions?

HTML:

```
<script>
    controller.init();
    controller.makeUIactions();
</script>

<div>
    <input type="button" id="ShuffleButton" style="margin-top:20px" value="Shuffle" data-inline="true">

    <input type="button" id="SubmitButton" style="margin-top:20px" value="Submit" data-inline="true">
</div>
```

Comment: *How do I pass by document object to makeUIactions?* Explain this a little more. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The `document` object is a global variable in a browser accessible from anywhere.  It does not need to be passed unless you're using some sort of embedded document like an iframe.

Comment: Why you want to pass that..

Comment: Can you show us the HTML? Seems there is no element with the ID of ’button'.

Comment: Try to load script at the end..or you can specify your functionalities inside `window.onload`..

Answer (score 2):

Your code is running BEFORE the DOM has been loaded thus, `document.getElementById("ShuffleButton")` cannot find the DOM element so it returns `null`.  When you then try `null.addEventListener()`, it throws the error you see.

You can fix it by moving this:

```
<script>
    controller.init();
    controller.makeUIactions();
</script>
```

to be right before your `</body>` tag so that the DOM elements are in place before the script runs.  See this answer [pure JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's $.ready() how to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the/9899701#9899701) for lots more details.